# conditionally select a column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In the query similar to this:

```
SELECT 
  COLUMN1,
  CASE WHEN 1=2 THEN
    COLUMN2
  END AS "COLUMN2"
FROM
  TABLE1
```

...it appears to always return COLUMN2 in the dataset with NULL values in it. I'd like to avoid that. Basically, in certain conditions one of the columns I am selecting is not applicable, therefore I don't want to select it at all. I know how to "hide" it in code, but I would like to achieve this in the database procedure if at all possible without overcomplicating the query.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why you want to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not possible. A query has to have a fixed set of columns that it returns (drawing from a known set of tables). That part is not dynamic, it needs to be known at "compile-time".

You need to remove the column in your application (or have multiple queries, potentially generated dynamically in client code).